# Run shiny application with arguments in terminal

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Like in the topic, I'd like to run shiny app with parameters. I need to specify the database file's path from which I will grab the data. The problem is that the file changes sometimes thus I have to modify the `file.path` every time.

This is the command I use when running application from terminal

```
R -e "shiny::runApp('../Shiny_visualization')"
```

I tried 
`R -e "shiny::runApp('../Shiny_visualization')" --args 'db_path'` yet I got an error.

Comment: what was the error?